# Insert a full woocommerce product page into another page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

No, I just couldn't find this anywhere else. (everything but)

Does anyone know how to (without using an iFrame) insert a full woocommerce single product page within another page (so it appears in it's entirety).

What I'm looking for is a way to create a new page, type some content (for example, a headline) implement some code (shortcode etc) and have the full woocommerce simple product page of my choice appear in its entirety at that point, allowing me to continue to add content thereafter.

Comment: include the desired template in your page using `get_template()` will do the trick for u

Comment: Thanks! That sounds like it would work but is beyond my capabilities to implement (perhaps I shouldn't have asked the knowledgeable people around here, whom I should have known would give a reply over my head). I've edited the question to see if that helps.